# Function call only works when MessageBox.Show() is included?

Tags: vb.net

In my current project I have a self-made audioplayer which is operated trough my musictimer() function. Below is a sub which orders the audioplayer to go to the next song when someone has clicked on a picture. This works perfectly.

```
Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
    If (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 > songBeingPlayed) Then
        musictimer("next")
    Else
        musictimer("stop")
    End If
End Sub
```

Below there is a sub which orders the player to play the next song when a song is finished playing. This sub also works but only when I have the MessageBox.Show("blabla") line in there. Otherwise it simply ignores the musictimer("next"). Obviously its quite annoying to have popup messages the entire times so I want it gone. Does anyone know whats going on? Im clueless.

```
Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange
    If AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped Then
        musictimer("next")
        MessageBox.Show("blabla")
    End If
End Sub
```

My very messy musictimer function.

```
Function musictimer(ByVal action)
    If action Is "initial" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0:00"
        Timer1.Stop()
        secondsCounter = 1
        doubledigitsecondCounter = 0
        minuteCounter = 0
    End If

    If action Is "reset" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0:00"
        Timer1.Stop()
        secondsCounter = 1
        doubledigitsecondCounter = 0
        minuteCounter = 0
        Me.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ""
        changePlayButton("play")
    End If

    If action Is "start" Then
        If (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0) Then
            Me.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = directoryPath + listboxpl(songBeingPlayed)
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
            Timer1.Start()
            changePlayButton("pause")
        End If
    End If

    If action Is "pause" Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause()
        changePlayButton("play")
    End If

    If action Is "next" Then
        If (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 > songBeingPlayed) Then
            songBeingPlayed += 1
            musictimer("reset")
            musictimer("start")
            changePlayButton("pause")
        Else
            musictimer("pause")
        End If
    End If

    If action Is "previous" Then
        If (songBeingPlayed > 0) Then
            songBeingPlayed -= 1
            musictimer("reset")
            musictimer("start")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I've added the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PlayStateChanged event is quite notorious.  It was really meant to just update a UI element that shows the state.  Doing anything with the player in that event is very troublesome.  A call to MessagBox can have an affect because it pumps a message loop, always a big deal for ActiveX controls.

The best way to stay out of trouble is by *delaying* your code, making it run *after* the event was fired and the player is back into a quiescent state.  Elegantly done by using the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  Like this:

```
Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange
    If e.newState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf NextSong))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NextSong()
    musictimer("next")
End Sub
```